Unsigned-to-two's complement algorithm
This question is inspired by Equation 2.8 in Bryant & O'Hallaron's Computer Systems which says:

$B2U_w (\vec{x})$ (binary-to-unsigned) and $B2T_w (\vec{x})$ (binary-to-two's complement) can be combined to give (unsigned-to-two's complement):
$$U2T_w(u) = -u_{w-1} 2^{w} + u$$

($u_{w-1}$ is the most-significant bit of unsigned $u$ represented in binary form.) Where the mentioned equations are:

$$B2U_w(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=0}^{w-1} x_i 2^i$$
$$B2T_w(\vec{x}) = -x_{w-1} 2^{w-1} + \sum_{i=0}^{w-2} x_i 2^i$$

(Note $\vec{x}$ represents a bit vector, i.e. $[x_{w-1}, x_{w-2}, ..., x_1, x_0]$.) While I understand $U2T$ intuitively, I would like to derive/'combine' the equations as instructed. It seems clear the first step should be deriving the inverse of $B2U$ (i.e. $U2B$); after we can simply verify $U2B_w(B2T_w(u)) = U2T_w(u)$. However, my attempt to invert $B2U$ devolves into a kind of division algorithm which I don't know how to represent in a proof.
How can we derive $U2T$ from $B2U$ and $B2T$?

I don't think the authors mean "combine" in any formal sense that implies a completely mechanical process.
Here we can see that $\mathrm{B2U}$ and $\mathrm{B2T}$ use quite similar formulas. It's not difficult to rewrite $\mathrm{B2T}$ so that $\mathrm{B2U}$ appears explicitly as a subterm.
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{B2T}(x) & = -x_{w-1}2^{w-1}+\sum^{w-2}_{i=0}x_i2^i \\
& = -x_{w-1}2^{w-1} - x_{w-1}2^{w-1} +\sum^{w-1}_{i=0}x_i2^i \\
& = -x_{w-1}2^w + \mathrm{B2U}(x)
\end{align*}$$
We obtain $\mathrm{U2T}(u)$ without relying on an explicit formula for the inverse of $\mathrm{B2U}$:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{U2T}(u)& = \mathrm{B2T}(\mathrm{B2U}^{-1}(u)) \\
& = -(\mathrm{B2U}^{-1}(u))_{w-1}2^w + \mathrm{B2U}(\mathrm{B2U}^{-1}(u)) \\
& = -u_{w-1}2^w + u
\end{align*}$$
